# Replace NaN values in a dataframe with values in a series python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
    id     count
0     10       3
1     20       4
2     30       5
3     40       NaN
4     50       NaN
5     60       NaN
6     70       NaN
```

also i have another pandas series s

```
0   1000
1   2000
2   3000
3   4000
```

what i want to do is replace the NaN values in my df with the respective values from series s.
my final output should be

```
    id     count
0     10       3
1     20       4
2     30       5
3     40       1000
4     50       2000
5     60       3000
6     70       4000
```

Any ideas how do achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem `lenght` of `Series` is different as length of `NaN` values in column `count`. So you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) `Series` by length of `NaN`:

```
s = pd.Series({0: 1000, 1: 2000, 2: 3000, 3: 4000, 5: 5000})
print (s)
0    1000
1    2000
2    3000
3    4000
5    5000
dtype: int64

df.loc[df['count'].isnull(), 'count'] = 
s.reindex(np.arange(df['count'].isnull().sum())).values
print (df)
   id   count
0  10     3.0
1  20     4.0
2  30     5.0
3  40  1000.0
4  50  2000.0
5  60  3000.0
6  70  4000.0
```

Comment: i edited my question, the index of my series starts from 0 and not 3.

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
df.count[df.count.isnull()] = s.values
```

Comment: i edited my question, the index of my series starts from 0 and not 3.

Comment: getting this error. `'function' object has no attribute 'isnull'`

Comment: need `df.loc[df['count'].isnull(), 'count'] = s.values`

Comment: @jezrael getting error after replacing with your code `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I prefer iterrows for its readability.

```
counter = 0    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['count'].isnull():
        df.set_value(index, 'count', s[counter])
        counter += 1
```

I might add that this 'merging' of dataframe + series is a bit odd, and prone to bizarre errors. If you can somehow get the series into the same format as the dataframe (aka add some index/column tags, then you might be better served by the merge function).

Comment: Read up on set_value here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

Comment: ^I agree. The other solution by jezrael makes good sense, but only after some headscratching and staring. Or I'm just a bit rookie in this case! I'm hoping OP doesn't have to go this route of series merging into dataframe, which seems quite awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-index your Series with indexes of `np.nan` from dataframe and than `fillna()` with your Series:

```
s.index = np.where(df['count'].isnull())[0]
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(s)
print(df)

   id   count
0  10     3.0
1  20     4.0
2  30     5.0
3  40  1000.0
4  50  2000.0
5  60  3000.0
6  70  4000.0
```